# Angularjs http post request - params are not reaching to server

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create post request with angularjs. This is my code for adding an supplier to server.

```
SupplierService.addNewSupplier = function(supplier)  {
    alert (supplier.name);
    alert (supplier.mobile);
    var Indata = {'name': supplier.name, 'mobile': supplier.mobile};
    //var Indata = {'product': $scope.product, 'product2': $scope.product2 };
    var req = {
        url: SupplierURL,
        method: 'POST',
        params: Indata,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    };

    //$http.post(SupplierURL, Indata)
    $http(req)
        .then(function(success){
            console.log(success);
            //SupplierList.push({id: data, name: supplier.name, mobile: supplier.mobile});
            supplier.name = "";
            supplier.mobile = "";
        },function (error){
            console.log(error);

            alert ('Supplier add error.');
        });

};
```

After making the request, callback is coming to error part and in console log i can see.

{error: true, message: "Failed to create supplier. Please try again", name: null, mobile: null}

Why name and mobile is not reaching to server. Same request works fine with postman(api testing tool). So i don't thing there can be anu issue in server side code. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Use `data` instead of `params` on line 9. `params` is for `GET` requests.

Comment: Try to use classical way:  $http.post(yourUrl, Indata);

Answer (score 0):

From the $http documentation you can clearly see request parameters:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

```
var req = {
 method: 'POST',
 url: 'http://example.com',
 headers: {
   'Content-Type': undefined
 },
 data: { test: 'test' }
}

$http(req).then(function(){...}, function(){...});
```

So, in your case you need to switch `params` with `data`:

```
 var req = {
        url: SupplierURL,
        method: 'POST',
        data: Indata,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    };
```